# Simples click em Jquery não funciona

Tags: jquery

Quero que quando eu clicar no `span` a `ul` apareça.
O correto é usar o **parent**, não?

```js
$(".produtosMenu li span").click(function() {
  $(".produtosSubmenu").parent().addClass("dpb");
});
```

```css
.produtosMenu li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: background-color .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.produtosMenu li span {
  font: 700 13px/40px"open sans";
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: #003a57;
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.produtosMenu li span:hover {
  background: url("../imagens/detalhesFlecha.png") #006ba1 no-repeat 210px 14px;
}
.produtosSubmenu {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
.produtosSubmenu li {
  font: 400 16px/16px"open sans";
  color: #16232e;
}
.produtosSubmenu li:hover {
  font: 600 16px/16px"open sans";
  color: #006ba1;
}
.dpb {
  display: block;
}
.dpn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="produtosMenu">
  <li>
    <span>Calotas</span>
    <ul class="produtosSubmenu">
      <li>Modelo 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Você quer que toda vez que o span seja clicado a lista abra se estiver fechada e feche se estiver aberta?

Comment: isso mesmo @ErlonCharles, essa tentativa até agora é só pra abrir mesmo, pensei em fazer um `else` para o efeito contrário

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para mostrar e esconder ao clicar no elemento você pode usar a função [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Caso queira somente mostar o elemento sem a opção de esconder ao clicar novamente, você pode usar a função [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) no lugar de `.toggle()`

Exemplo:

```js
$(".produtosMenu li span").click(function() {
  $(".produtosSubmenu").toggle();
});
```

```css
.produtosMenu li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: background-color .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.produtosMenu li span {
  font: 700 13px/40px"open sans";
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: #003a57;
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.produtosMenu li span:hover {
  background: url("../imagens/detalhesFlecha.png") #006ba1 no-repeat 210px 14px;
}
.produtosSubmenu {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
.produtosSubmenu li {
  font: 400 16px/16px"open sans";
  color: #16232e;
}
.produtosSubmenu li:hover {
  font: 600 16px/16px"open sans";
  color: #006ba1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="produtosMenu">
  <li>
    <span>Calotas</span>
    <ul class="produtosSubmenu">
      <li>Modelo 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ah entendi, o estranho é que copiei o Jquery que você escreveu, aqui funcionou, mas não na minha página.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito sua pergunta, mas caso queira que toda vez que o `span` seja clicado a lista abra se estiver fechada e feche se estiver aberto você vai precisar utilizar a função [`.toogle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) do *jQuery* que faz exatamente isso permitindo inclusive que animações sejam feitas.

No exemplo abaixo inclui uma animação [`fade`](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/) e um [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) que vai impedir que caso u usuário de muitos cliques seguidos a `ul` fique fechando e abrindo tepetidamente mesmo depois dos cliques pararem.

### jQuery

```
$(".produtosMenu li span").click(function() {
  $(".produtosSubmenu").stop().toggle("fade");
});
```

### Css

```
.produtosMenu li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: background-color .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.produtosMenu li span {
  font: 700 13px/40px"open sans";
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: #003a57;
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.produtosMenu li span:hover {
  background: url("../imagens/detalhesFlecha.png") #006ba1 no-repeat 210px 14px;
}
.produtosSubmenu {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
.produtosSubmenu li {
  font: 400 16px/16px"open sans";
  color: #16232e;
}
.produtosSubmenu li:hover {
  font: 600 16px/16px"open sans";
  color: #006ba1;
}
```

### Html

```
<ul class="produtosMenu">
  <li>
    <span>Calotas</span>
    <ul class="produtosSubmenu">
      <li>Modelo 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfeito, o que eu quero, é que quando o usuário clique no `span` **calotas** no caso, a `<ul class="produtosSubmenu">` apareça, pois ela está como `display:none`

Comment: Confere no [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jqo8td8b/) como funciona, ele faz exatamente isso.

Comment: executei o código aqui mesmo e não funcionou

Comment: não funcionou na minha máquina tambem

Comment: Está aparecendo algum erro de javascript no console?

Comment: Infelizmente não

Answer (score 0):

Usa assim fica mais fácil

```
$(".produtosMenu li span").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
});
```

Comment: também não funcionou =/